# Error: Fatal error encountered during command execution

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015

Error: Fatal error encountered during command execution
Here is my code:

```
 public static int AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = MySqlCommand.GetConnection();
        string insertStatement =
            "INSERT INTO customer (CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME, CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME, CUSTOMER_CITY, CUSTOMER_STATE, CUSTOMER_STREET_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_STREET, CUSTOMER_PHONE) " +
            "VALUES (@CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME, @CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME, @CUSTOMER_CITY, @CUSTOMER_STATE, @CUSTOMER_STREET_NUMBER, @CUSTOMER_STREET, @CUSTOMER_PHONE)";
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand insertCommand =
            new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(insertStatement, connection);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME", customer.FirstName);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
           "@CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME", customer.LastName);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@CUSTOMER_STREET_NUMBER", customer.StreetNumber);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
             "@CUSTOMER_STREET_NAME", customer.Street);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@CUSTOMER_CITY", customer.City);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@CUSTOMER_STATE", customer.State);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@CUSTOMER_PHONE", customer.Phone);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string selectStatement =
               "SELECT MAX(CUST_ID) FROM customer";
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand selectCommand =
                new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);
            int customerID = Convert.ToInt32(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());
            return customerID;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="oldCustomer"></param>
    /// <param name="newCustomer"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool UpdateCustomer(Customer oldCustomer, 
        Customer newCustomer)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = MySqlCommand.GetConnection();
        string updateStatement =
            "UPDATE customer SET " +
            "CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME = @NewCUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME, " +
            "CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME = @NewCUSTOMER_LAST_NAME, " +
            "CUSTOMER_STREET = @NewCUSTOMER_STREET, " +
            "CUSTOMER_STREET_NUMBER = @vCUSTOMER_STREET_NUMBER" +
            "CUSTOMER_CITY = @NewCUSTOMER_CITY, " +
            "CUSTOMER_STATE = @NewCUSTOMER_STATE, " +
            "CUSTOMER_PHONE = @NewCUSTOMER_PHONE " +
            "WHERE " +
            "CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME = @CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME, " +
            "CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME = @CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME, " +
            "CUSTOMER_STREET = @OldCUSTOMER_STREET, " +
            "CUSTOMER_STREET_NUMBER = @OldCUSTOMER_STREET_NUMBER" +
            "AND CUSTOMER_CITY = @OldCUSTOMER_CITY " +
            "AND CUSTOMER_STATE = @OldCUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME " +
            "AND CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME = @OldCUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME;";
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand updateCommand =
            new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(updateStatement, connection);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@NewFirstName", newCustomer.FirstName);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
           "@NewLastName", newCustomer.LastName);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@NewStreet", newCustomer.Street);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@NewStreetNumber", newCustomer.StreetNumber);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@CUSTOMER_CITY", newCustomer.City);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@CUSTOMER_STATE", newCustomer.State);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@NEW_PHONE", newCustomer.Phone);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
           "@OldFirstName", oldCustomer.FirstName);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
           "@OldLastName", oldCustomer.LastName);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
           "@OldStreet", oldCustomer.Street);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@OldStreetNumber", oldCustomer.StreetNumber);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@OldCity", oldCustomer.City);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@OldState", oldCustomer.State);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@OldCUSTOMER_PHONE", oldCustomer.Phone);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            int count = updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (count > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Where am I going wrong? I have tried other changes recommended in other posts that I have viewed without any luck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does it fail during the update or the insert?

Comment: It fails during both the add and update functionality.

Comment: what is your error exactly?

Comment: @reds When i try running either the add or update functionality in my program an error reading "Fatal Error during command execution".

Comment: Your code is inserting a record and getting a record too after inserting into your database? but you open the connection only once without closing the first one.

Comment: My code is able to pull a record from a database and modify that information or to be able to a new record to the database using the add functionality.

Comment: I don't even see your connectionString.

Comment: I didn't post that part of the code because i am able to make the connection. I only posted the code that i am having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert first then follow the next query if succeed:

```
public static int AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = MySqlCommand.GetConnection();
        connection.Open();
        string insertStatement =
            "INSERT INTO customer (CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME, CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME, CUSTOMER_CITY, CUSTOMER_STATE, CUSTOMER_STREET_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_STREET, CUSTOMER_PHONE) " +
            "VALUES (@CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME, @CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME, @CUSTOMER_CITY, @CUSTOMER_STATE, @CUSTOMER_STREET_NUMBER, @CUSTOMER_STREET, @CUSTOMER_PHONE)";
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand insertCommand =
            new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(insertStatement, connection);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME", customer.FirstName);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
           "@CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME", customer.LastName);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@CUSTOMER_STREET_NUMBER", customer.StreetNumber);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
             "@CUSTOMER_STREET_NAME", customer.Street);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@CUSTOMER_CITY", customer.City);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@CUSTOMER_STATE", customer.State);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@CUSTOMER_PHONE", customer.Phone);
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
```

Replace:

**From:**

```
MySqlConnection connection = MySqlCommand.GetConnection();
```

**To:**

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("YourConnectionStringHere");
```

Comment: Is record inserted after this execution?